# How to know if a service container is ready for connections?

Tags: service, docker, docker-compose

I frequently run into this issue creating stacks in Docker. Say I have a LAMP stack in docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_VARIOUS: things
web:
    build: .
    links:
        - db
    ports:
        - "80"
    entrypoint:
        - setup-and-start
```

And the `setup-and-start` script looks like this:

```
wait_for_mysql && initialize
```

If the web container has mysql-client installed on it, then I can easily define `wait_for_mysql`:

```
wait_for_mysql() {
    local timeout=10
    while sleep 1; do
        mysql [credentials] -e 'select 1;' && return 0
        (( --timeout <= 0 )) && break
    done
    echo 'Failed to initialize mysql within time limit.' >&2
    return 1
}
```

But many containers won't have the client. Rather than install it into every lightweight container, is there a reasonable way I can check if mysql is up and running before initializing my application? It should work on most Docker containers, but doesn't have to be a perfect validation of mysql; even checking for an expected telnet response would probably be acceptable (except that telnet is also not commonly on docker images).

Comment: Can you connect with the same application that runs your website? - if using RoR, use a rake task, if using php, use a php script - this will surely have the necessary libraries to connect to mysql, as it needs them to run the app.

Comment: @Michael Good question: I should clarify that I'm trying to come up with something I can reuse without worrying about which particular web container I'm on. That said, your suggestion is a good one and I might fall back to that.

Comment: mysql has it's own protocol, so the only hack is to curl the port and get a very bad mysql return, it checks that mysql is listening on that port, and nothing more, it is not a good way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

The question is covered in the [Docker Compose FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/). Short answer there is no good way, and this is by design. Though this use case is very common in testing and small applications for any significant system `wait for startup` is an anti-pattern.

> The problem of waiting for a database to be ready is really just a
>   subset of a much larger problem of distributed systems. In production,
>   your database could become unavailable or move hosts at any time. The
>   application needs to be resilient to these types of failures.

Comment: Interesting point, but generally applications are designed for resilience when they are services, not when they are being initialized. `rake db:setup` (for example) cannot be designed to be resilient enough to set up a database it cannot connect to.